# PHPUnit test function outside class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am very new to PHPUnit and unit-testing, so I have a questing:
Can I test a function outside a class like:

```
    function odd_or_even( $num ) {
    return $num%2; // Returns 0 for odd and 1 for even
}

class test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function odd_or_even_to_true() {
        $this->assetTrue( odd_or_even( 4 ) == true );
    }
}
```

Right now it just returns:

```
No tests found in class "test".
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to prefix your function names with 'test' in order for them to be recognized as a test.

[From the documentation:](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

> 3. The tests are public methods that are named test*.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the @test annotation in a method's docblock to mark it as a test method.

There should be no problem calling `odd_or_even()`.

For example:

```
class test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function test_odd_or_even_to_true() {
        $this->assertTrue( odd_or_even( 4 ) == true );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Theadamlt: also in `odd_or_even( 4 ) == true` the part `== true` is redundant, as long as you use `assertTrue`

Comment: +1 for mentioning using the @test annotation. Excellent.

Comment: What's the best way to import functions to a test? I tried require('function.php'), but that cause a 

1) test::test_me
Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of phpunit, this is how I write test.php to test a single function:

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class test extends TestCase
{
   public function test_odd_or_even_to_true()
   {
      $this->assertTrue(
         odd_or_even(4) == 0
      );
   }
}
```

And I run the test this way:

./phpunit --bootstrap file_with_source_code.php ./tests/test.php